# Calling Katharsis JSONApi JsonApiFindAllWithIds

Tags: java, json-api, katharsis

I am using Kathatrsis for my REST API. I am also new to the JSONApi spec. I for the life of me cant figure out the url pattern to call the `@JsonApiFindAllWithIds` method.

For example, say it is annotated as:

```
@JsonApiFindAllWithIds
public Iterable<ThriftType> findAll(Iterable<String> iterable, QueryParams queryParams) {
```

And if I call the URL (my resource is called test):

```
http://localhost:8080/test/1?filter[test][otherId][EQ]=9
```

I would expect it to hit that method, with an iterable list containing `1` and a query param object containing my filter.

However, it calls my `@JsonApiFindOne` method described as:

```
@JsonApiFindOne
public ThriftType findOne(String id) {
```

Can you tell me the proper url format to hit my `@JsonApiFindAllWithIds` method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JsonAliFindAllWithIds is for scenarios where there are more than one id for which value needs to be fetched. 
For eg

http://localhost:8080/test/1,2

Would call findallwithids method whereas providing a single
Id would call findone method. 
Hope it helps